# parent.parent.window.location.href is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am getting a strange problem. I am using fancybox in my project where after clicking on the link of the fancybox I am closing it and trying to reload the parent window. I am using this code.

```
<script>
    parent.$.fancybox.close();  
    parent.parent.window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>home/job_posting/<?php echo $id ;?>';
</script>
```

It is working locally but when the thing trying to run it in live server it is not working. I am using codeigniter framework and doing this in my controller method.

Please help.

Comment: can you not add the actual URL eg. window.location.href= 'http : //www.example.com/'?

Comment: Are you able to view the source, and post the HTML that is being output (rather than the PHP code being used to generate it)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are just trying to reload the *parent* window after closing fancybox, then just close fancybox from within the opened page (the way you are doing it) like

```
<script>
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
</script>
```

... and reload the *parent* page from itself adding to your fancybox custom script the `afterClose` callback like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // other API options here
    afterClose : function() {
        location.reload();
        return;
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if you are not just trying to reload the *parent* page but actually trying to redirect to another page, then use `window.location.pathname` if you are using a relative path or `window.location.href` for a full path.

You may also want to try `self.location.href`.

**NOTE** : `afterClose` is for fancybox v2.x, For fancybox v1.3.4 use `onClosed` instead.